# How do I read the AssemblyFileVersion of a C# DLL from Visual Basic?

Tags: c#, vb6, assemblyversionattribute

I am invoking a C# object from a Visual Basic 6.0 sub routine (don't ask).
How do I get the AssemblyFileVersion from Visual Basic?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do this from VB6, then you will need something like this:

http://www.visualbasic.happycodings.com/Files_Directories_Drives/code30.html

Using the Windows API should give you what you need.

EDIT:

Don't know if this might also help:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186118

Shows how to use the FileSystemObject which could be an easier way to get file information.